# libtrace to analyze a trace file in C

Tags: c

I need some direction, I want to write a libtrace program using C to analyse a trace file and count the number of packets and bytes observed each minute for the TCP and UDP protocol. I am very new to C and i need direction on this.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

There is a libtrace tutorial at https://github.com/LibtraceTeam/libtrace/wiki/Tutorial

Start by working through that.

Since this appears to be the assignment for COMPX514 I suggest that if you have further questions you approach the teaching staff directly